# Is there a closed form for $\sum \frac{1}{k!}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Let $F = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}a_kx^k$ be a formal power series and define $F_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\binom{n}{k}a_kx^k$. Is it possible to define $F_n$ starting from $F$ by some elementary operations? I don't know what kind of operations I mean, probably sum, multiplication, powering, composition, differentation, integration...

In particular, is there a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^k$ ?

Sorry if this question lacks of details, but I don't know anything about generating functions, combinatorics and so on. I hope I can apply the answer to another field.

Comment: What variable are you summing over? Over what range?

Comment: @Blitzer Edited

Comment: $F_{n,m}$ is a polynomial of degree min(m,n). It's not obvious to me how to simplify it. You could expand it for small values of m and n and see if you get anything you recognize. Perhaps start with $F_{n,n}$ for a few values and look in OEIS for the results for, say, $F_{10,10}$.

Comment: According to wolfram alpha, this is equal to the "generalized hypergeometric function" ${}_2F_2(-m,-n;1,1;x)$. So the answer is probably no, there is no elementary closed expression.

Comment: It's essentially a finite sum. By convention ${n \choose k}$ and ${m \choose k}$ are $0$ for all $k > \min \{ m,n\}$ unless you are using some other definition like ${x \choose k} =\frac{x(x-1) \ldots(x-k+1)}{k!}$

Comment: @Andre.J Yes, it is a finite sum

Answer (score 2):

We can use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> With $F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}$ we have
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F_n(x)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[z^k](1+z)^n a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{1}\\
> &=[z^0](1+z)^n\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{-k}a_k\frac{x^k}{k!}\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^0](1+z)^nF\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$.
- In (2) we use the rule$[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Long Comment:**

There is a simple pattern for $S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}x^k$

$$n=1:\;\;\;\;S_{m,1}=1+m$$
$$n=2:\;\;\;\;S_{m,2}=1+2mx+\frac{(m-1)m}{(2!)^2}x^2$$
$$n=3:\;\;\;\;S_{m,3}=1+3mx+\frac{3(m-1)m}{(2!)^2}x^2+\frac{(m-2)(m-1)m}{(3!)^2}x^3$$
$$n=4:\;\;\;\;S_{m,4}=1+4mx+\frac{6(m-1)m}{(2!)^2}x^2+\frac{4(m-2)(m-1)m}{(3!)^2}x^3+\frac{(m-3)(m-2)(m-1)m}{(4!)^2}x^4$$

The relations are symmetric between $m$ and $n$.